# Como atribuir código HTML a uma variável JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```
<table class="al-center" style="width: 520px;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label class='control-label' for='auto'>RECEBIDO POR*</label>
                        <input  type='text' class='autofocus form_campos form_campos_simples' id='auto' name='verifica_nome'>
                        <input name='cliente' type='hidden'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label class='control-label' for='qtd'>QTD*</label>
                        <input  type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_ddd' id='qtd' name='qtd'>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Eu preciso colocar ele dentro de uma variável em JavaScript, que esta dentro deste código:

```
<script>
$('input[name="qtd"]').on('keyup click', function(){

    var qtd = $(this).val();

    if(qtd > 0) {
        $('#inputs table').remove();
        var appending = '<table class="al-center" style="width: 520px;">';

        for(var i = 1; i <= qtd; i++) {
            appending += 'Tenho que por ele aqui';
        }

        appending += '</table>';
        $('#inputs').append(appending);
    }else {
        $('#inputs table').remove();
    }
});
</script>
```

Funciona se eu colocar tudo em uma linha, o problema e que fica complicado para eu dar manutenção e entender o código.

Como colocar o HTML com a indentação dele?

Comment: Quais são as partes de esse código que precisas manter/modificar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

se preferir, ao invés de concatenar strings no seu código, poderá usar um recurso do `HTML5`, `templates`.

caso precise de um `template` mais complexo e manter o código legível seja importante para você, aconselho que procure alguma `Template Engine`, como por exemplo o [HandleBars](http://handlebarsjs.com)

segue um exemplo simples usando a tag `template`.

```js
var qtd = document.getElementById("qtd");
var tabela = document.getElementById("tabela");
var tmplLinha = document.getElementById("tmplLinha").content;

qtd.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
  while (tabela.firstChild) {
    tabela.removeChild(tabela.firstChild);
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < qtd.valueAsNumber; i++) {
    var linha = document.importNode(tmplLinha, true);
    tabela.appendChild(linha);
  }
})
```

```html
<label>
  Quantidade:
  <input type="number" id="qtd" name="qtd" />
</label>

<table id="tabela" class="al-center" style="width: 520px;">

</table>

<template id="tmplLinha">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='form-group'>
        <label class='control-label' for='auto'>RECEBIDO POR*</label>
        <input  type='text' class='autofocus form_campos form_campos_simples' id='auto' name='verifica_nome'>
        <input name='cliente' type='hidden'>
      </div>
      <div class='form-group'>
        <label class='control-label' for='qtd'>QTD*</label>
        <input  type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_ddd' id='qtd' name='qtd'>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: Templates é a maneira mais semantica para este tipo de problema. +1

Answer (score 2):

Podemos dizer que não dá sem fazer bastante gambiarra.

```
var html = '
  <div>                              \
    <span>\'Algo aqui\'</span>       \
  </div>                             \
';
```

Se tiver aspas simples tem que escapar ela.

Fora isto teria que ir concatenando, acho que não compensa.

No EcmaScript 6, que talvez não ainda seja seguro adotar para sites públicos, é possível fazer assim:

```
var html = `
  <div>
    <span>Algo aqui</span>
  </div>
`;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/MultiLine.js).

Comment: Tem uma gambiarra que pode ser feita em javascript para definir "múltiplas linhas"

Comment: Que eu saiba em JS mesmo, só assim. Mas vai saber... Dá para criar o arquivo do JS com um `include` do HTML. É gambi, funciona, mas não é fazer múltiplas linhas.

Comment: Não, tem um jeito de fazer uma gambiarra com o comentário da função. Daí você escreve dentro do comentário e captura a string.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sei qual você está dizendo, serial algo [assim](https://jsfiddle.net/04h3Laq2/) não é ?